# Add flagging option to new review queues

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, flags

Related:

[New review queue needs a "Convert to comment" option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/new-review-queue-needs-a-convert-to-comment-option)

[VLQ review queue, option for "this should be a comment"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/vlq-review-queue-option-for-this-should-be-a-comment)

I was reviewing an item in the Very Low Quality queue for Code Review (which I sadly cannot link to) that was most definitely not an answer and should have been a comment, because it was asking for clarification from the asker.

I understand that converting to a comment is a mod privilege, but there isn't even a way to get a moderator's attention from the review queue screen, something I believe would be an incredibly useful feature for those times when something needs to be handled by a mod.

I would propose that it act identically to the ordinary flag button.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is useful. A post in the VLQ queue was most likely already flagged, or put there automatically. It should most likely be deleted.

If the answer was from a user that cannot comment, and therefore answers, we shouldn't reward that with a moderator action to convert that answer to a comment.

Only in cases where the answer was actually a high quality comment, it *could* be kept, but I don't think it is worth the effort to create that option for just this. Keep in mind that comments are just temporary stuff that could be deleted *any* time.

Comment: VLQ was just an example queue where I noticed it. I believe it would be useful in most, if not all queues. Additionally the ability to signal a moderator for more serious offences would be helpful.

Comment: @NickUdell: For that last you can go to the original post. The items in the queue are already subject to closing/deleting, so to prevent too much (useless) flags I think they made it a little harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

Still you can go to the post (click "link" in the right sidebar) and flag it, then return back and recommend deletion with "No comment needed".

Comment: This seems an awkward way around accessing what I feel should be a first-class feature for reviewers. If anybody can flag on a question, reviewers should definitely be able to flag.